# Translate for loop to a while and do while loop in Java

Tags: java

I created a couple for loops that print lines as such (each new number starts a new line, it doesn't show here):

1
22
333
4444

etc. until it reaches 9 then goes back down to 1.

I am supposed to translate it into both a while and do while loop and have been trying for the past hour and can't seem to do it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
   for (int x=1;  x <= 9; x++) {
       for (int y = 1; y <=x ; y++){
           System.out.print( x + "");
           }
       System.out.println();
       }

    // TODO code application logic here
  for (int x=9;  x >=1; x--) {
       for (int y = 1; y <=x ; y++){
           System.out.print( x + "");
           }
       System.out.println();

       }   int y =1;
  int x = 1;
  while (x <9){

      while (y <=x){
          y++;
  System.out.print(x +"");{
  }
  System.out.println();
}
 x++;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we'll help you with that

Comment: I tried editing and it wouldn't allow me, but I've tried: 

   int y =1;
      int x = 1;
      while (x <9){
       x++;
          while (y <=x){
              y++;
      System.out.print(x +"");{
      }
      System.out.println();
}

it prints 1-9 but not the amount respective to the number.

Comment: `not the amount respective to the number`?  Hmm?

Comment: @user2836944 post your tried code in your question

Comment: Sorry I worded that poorly, what I mean is not "1, 22, 333, 4444" etc.

Comment: Is that what the `for` loops print?

Comment: Yes, the for loops print 1,22,333... to 9 and then back to 1.

Comment: If you can't edit in the code you tried, can you delete this question and post a new question with the code you tried?

Comment: I wasn't able to do it when I tried again, someone named David was editing it when I tried the first time. An admin I assume.

Comment: put your x++; at the end of the inner loop. Because the value increased by 1 at the loop starts. Then it will print upto 8

Comment: In `for` loops, the `update statement` (the `x++`) is the last thing executed, after the body of the loop.  So if you're translating from a `for` loop to a `while` loop, it should also be the very last statement.

Comment: I updated what I have so far. It prints the 1-9 and 9-1 from the for statements and now just 1-9  plainly (1,2,3,4...). It's a definite start. I understand and respect that no one is flatout giving me the answer, and that is good because I need to learn. Suggestions for my next step?

Comment: place the System.out.println(); outside of the inner loop

Comment: Done, now I have them vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your while loop:

```
int y = 1;
int x = 1;

while (x < 9) {

    y = 1;
    while (y <= x) {
            y++;

        System.out.print(x + "");


    }
    System.out.println();
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Modified to X<10 instead of 9 and it prints properly, I'm going to try to figure the rest on my own and come back if I can't get it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

A `for` loop statement has three parts in the `for (init; condition; post)`.  These parts are separated by semicolons.  The init part specifies an initial statement, the condition is what determines if the loop body is executed or not and the post specifies a post loop statement.

You can do the same thing with a `while` loop except that instead of a single statement, it is actually several statements.  However a `while` loop is not exactly like a `for` loop since the `continue` statement and how it behaves is a concern. More about that later.

A hint is that the various parts of the `for` statement are separated by semicolons which are also used to separate statements in Java.

Consider the following `for` loop source example.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // for loop body
}
```

So you would have an init statement before the loop statement, `i = 0` then the loop statement itself containing the condition, `i < 5`, and as the last line in the loop before the closing curly brace, you would put the post loop condition, `i++`.

The `do while` is a bit more complicated because of when the `while` condition is evaluated.  In both the `for` loop and the `while` loop, the condition is evaluated and if the expression is not true then the loop body is not executed at all, it is skipped.  In the case of the `for` loop, the init statement is executed and then the condition is evaluated to determine if the `for` loop body should be executed.  Since a `while` loop does not have an init statement as part of the `while` statement, the condition is evaluated and if not true, the `while` loop body is not executed.

A `do while` loop has a condition that is not evaluated until after the first time through the `do while` loop body.  So the statements within the `do while` loop are always executed at least once.  Then the `do while` condition is evaluated and if true, execution returns to the top where the `do` is and the `do while` loop body is executed again.

Some code of several variations of loops where the init is `i = 0` and where the condition is `i < 5` and the post is `i++`.  In all cases I have the variable `i` defined out side of the loop body.  In the case of a `for` loop, defining the variable `i` within the `for` statement causes the scope of the variable `i`, its visibility, to be restricted to the `for` loop body which would not be the case for the other types of loops.

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // for loop body
}

int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  // while loop body
  i++;
}


int i = 0;
do {
  // do while loop body
  i++;
} while (i < 5);
```

I mentioned that what happens when the `continue` statement is executed can make a difference when comparing these forms of loops. The way to think of it is that when a `continue` statement is executed then there is a jump to the closing brace of the loop statement enclosing the `continue` statement. So this introduces something to consider.

Look at the above examples but with a `continue` statement. In all of the examples below there is a `continue` statement which causes execution to skip to the end of the loop body when the variable `i` has a value of 3.

With this change the `for` loop will continue incrementing the variable `i` because it's post, the third part of the `for` statement, is executed at the end of the loop. However with the `while` loop and the `do while` loop, the incrementing of the variable `i` is part of the loop body so when the `continue` is executed skipping to the end of the loop, the increment of the variable `i` is also skipped.

```
int i;
// first time init variable i to zero then evaluate condition
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  //  evaluate condition and execute loop body if true
  // for loop body
  if (i == 3)
      continue;  // when i == 3 continue is executed to skip to end of loop
}  // at point of braces, post executed, condition evaluated

int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {     // evaluate condition and execute loop body if true
  // while loop body
  if (i == 3)
      continue;  // when i == 3 continue is executed to skip to end of loop
  i++;      // variable i only incremented when this statement is executed
}  // braces indicate end of loop so jump back to top of loop


int i = 0;
do {
  // do while loop body
  if (i == 3)
      continue;  // when i == 3 continue is executed to skip to end of loop
  // more statements which may be skipped by the continue
  i++;      // variable i only incremented when this statement is executed
} while (i < 5);  // evaluate condition and jump to top of loop if true
```

You could make a change to the `do while` loop `while` condition to move the incrementing of the variable `i` into the `while` condition evaluation by using a pre-increment operator, the `++` operator, on the variable as in the following. We use the pre-increment operator because we want to increment the variable `i` before we check its value.

```
int i = -1;    // need to start at -1 since the while will increment at beginning of the loop
while (++i < 5) { // increment variable i, evaluate condition and body of loop if true
  // while loop body
  if (i == 3)
      continue;  // when i == 3 continue is executed to skip to end of loop
}  // braces indicate end of loop so jump back to top of loop

int i = 0;
do {
  // do while loop body
  if (i == 3)
      continue;  // when i == 3 continue is executed to skip to end of loop
  // more statements which may be skipped by the continue
} while (++i < 5);  // increment variable i, evaluate condition and jump to top of loop if true
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) is a construct that is extremely similar to a [`while` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), except that it provides some extra niceties that reduce [boilerplate code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code).

The beginning of a `for` loop sets your initial variable (in your case, x), your condition clause (`x <= 9`) and your incrementor (`x++`). A `while` loop does not do these things for, it simply runs a block of code while the condition clause in the `()` is met.

Converting a `for` loop to a `while` is simple-

`for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {`

```
int x = 0;
while(x < 10) {
    x++;
}
```

The `while` loop has all the same features as the `for` loop, but without the syntactic sugar. This should help you convert the loops in your question, and in general.